# Oracle -Character Encoding

Tags: oracle10g

I am facing  a peculiar problem where i need to update a particular value in database to say 'Hellò'. When i run  normal update statement the values are updated fine. But when i put it i a .sql script file and then run  the update statement  the last character gets replaced by a junk value. Can some one enlighten me on this and how oracle processes script files?

Comment: What character encoding does Oracle expect in its .sql files? What character encoding does your text editor use? That's really all you need to check.

Comment: yeah ,i encountered a problem wher the character in the text file appears fine but the when the script is run the database gets inserted with junk values.

Answer (score 0):

If the update statement works then this isn't an issue with the character encoding in the database so there are two main culprits to look at; your software and your file encoding.

Check that you editor is UTF8 compliant - Notepad for example is not, but Wordpad is, and so are better editors like UltraEdit.  You also need to check that the file is saved as UTF8 since this in not always the default and if you edited and saved a file with Notepad, for example, it won't be UTF8 any more.

Once you have a UTF8 file then you must load it into the database via software that supports UTF8, which excludes SQLPlus in Windows 10g.  SQL Developer is OK.  If you want to use SQLPLus upgrade your client to 11g.  You don't say how you are loading it, so check that whatever you are using supported UTF8.